# How to add Image with a NSMutableDictionary and send the NSMutableDictionary to server using POST method in iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I want to send image with key in a NSMutableDictionary and send all other elements of dictionary to server using post & Nsurlsession in ios using objective C

Answer (score 0):

it's easy just convert UIImage to Data then set it in nsmutabledictionary

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image, 0.8);
```

Comment: you should convert NSMutabledictionary to JSON String then to NSData like this :


 NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
        bodyRequest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSData *postData = [bodyRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
 [request setHTTPBody:postData];